# I can get any emulators running in vs code

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

When I ever I try to create a new emulator I get this error
I can get any emulators running in vs code. I am getting No suitable Android AVD system images are available. You may need to install these using sdkmanager, for example: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"”

Answer (score 19):

```
Open Android Studio -> Configure -> AVD Manager -> Run Your Virtual Device
Visual studio code -> View -> Command palette... -> Flutter: Select Device -> choose your android device
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

As explicitly stated, you have **No suitable Android AVD system images available**. Create the AVD through Android Studio first so you can easily download a system image with a click.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Android Studio has changed, the new way to do this is:

[image: Virtual Device Manager]

From there you can

1. Select which image you want to download (downloads are massive, be warned)
2. Then click "next" to create the device
3. Reload VSCode, and your device will appear!

Answer (score 3):

You have to start Android Studio run the emulator first, before running a flutter project.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

1-Check if there is the path for Android SDK under System Environment Variable PATH(Open Windows Control Panel and go to System (Control Panel->System and Security->System, select Advanced system settings, click on Environment Variable, In System variables section click on 'Path').
The path for Android SDK is usually C:\Users\{Your laptop username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin.

If it is not there, find the Android SDK path and it (pointing to your ***SDK tools bin*** location)

2- Run Windows Powershell and run the following command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"

If it starts downloading then wait until it is finished and and run the sdkmanger command above again and finally go to VS code and click on ctrl-shift-p and write Flutter: Select Device-> Create Android Emulator and it will not show the error message.

3-If you get this error after running the *sdkmanger command : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema*
Then you have to install multiple versions of Java because there is something wrong in the last version  of Java. Download Java8 JDK from Oracle and install it. Then, copy Java8 JDK (it is usually C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271) and go to Environment variables (following the instructions in step 1). In system variables click on JAVA-HOME and paste the copied path of Java 8 instead of the path of last version and click on Ok.

4-Click on Path (in system variables) and search on the path of last java version, click on it and paste Java 8 **bin** location (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271**bin**) and click ok.

5-Exit the cmd and launch it (if you were using it before) and run the command: java -version
You should get the following output:

java version "1.8.0_271"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

Thus, we have installed Java8 JDK.

6-Now run Windows Powershell and run the following command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86" and it should start downloading.

7-Go to VS code and click on ctrl-shift-p and write Flutter: Select Device-> Create Android Emulator and it will not show the error message.

8-You can delete Java8 JDK and JRE now and reset the path of JAVA-HOME (copy the location of the last Java JDK and paste it there) and the path of ***Java bin*** to the original Path (System Variables->Path and change it to the ***Java bin*** location of the last version)

Comment: This worked for me thanks! I only needed one of these though (it comes up in PS for anyone else looking here with the command to run). Running this exact command didn't work because, I think, I had the other things installed and PS was getting confused.

I also didnt need ```*bin*```, the regular path worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same error as I was running out of space in my home folder. Cleaning up some space help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a device first:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select Tools/Device Manager
3. Press Create Device button
4. Select the device that you want

Then, you can use it in your vs code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this error when the Android emulator you're trying to use doesn't have the required system image installed. I encountered this error while attempting to run an Android emulator in VSCode on my new MacBook before properly configuring it.

To resolve this issue, you first need to make sure that the SDK tools required to use the Android emulator are installed.

1. Open Android Studio.
2. In the top nav bar, click Tools -> SDK Manager.
3. Click SDK Tools, (highlighted in blue).
4. Check `Android Emulator` and `Android SDK Platform-Tools`.
5. Click `Apply` followed by `Ok`, then `Finish` once the installation is complete.

Once you've installed the SDK tools, create a device by following these steps:

1. In Android Studio, in the top nav bar, click Tools -> Device Manager.
2. Click `Create Device` then select the device.
3. In the 'System Image' screen, select a system image. If you're not sure which one to select, click the API level distribution chart link on the right panel next to the list of system images.
4. Click 'Next' and wait for the operating system image to download.
5. Once the download is complete, the emulator device will appear in the Device Manager in Android Studio. Note that if you're using VSCode, you'll need to restart it for the new emulator to appear.

Comment: @tchrist No, my answer was not generated by an AI. If you actually followed the steps, you'll see that I used a recent version of Android Studio, which an AI language wouldn't have up-to-date data on. You can see also how detailed my answer is and if you look at my previous answers, you'll see that I use the same format. I only answer questions for errors that I have been stuck on so I find this insulting.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping. Your style threw me off track.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to set PATH in system environment variable
so, How to do that ?.., See here..
go to system environment variable then click to "environment variables.." after that you will get this screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhz1A.png)

and then click to the PATH once and then click to edit button. After  that there will be another screen in which browse option will there then you just browse to the path where you unzipped the flutter zip folder. and then select the bin folder uynder the flutter folder and then click  ok and your flutter path has selected now,
after giving the right path you just to windows shell or flutter terminal and paste this
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"    there and do enter after some time it will get downloaded and you can create new emulatr