# No Suitable Android AVD Available

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

No suitable Android AVD System images are available

Comment: So? Did you try installing them using the command suggested? Give us at least _some_ info on your system, config, and whether you have made any effort yet.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can get any emulators running in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090813/i-can-get-any-emulators-running-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 8):

This happens when your Android SDK does not have the required components downloaded to create the type of emulator Flutter is trying to create. As notced in the message, the fix is to run:

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

If you get an error like `sdkmanager not found` you'll need to put the full path to your Android SDK's `tools/bin` folder (or to add that folder to your `PATH` and try again).

Answer (score 4):

Follow the following steps:

1. Run sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"
   If it starts downloading then you are done. Otherwise, go to step 2
2. Check if there is a path for Android SDK under System Environment Variable PATH(Open Windows Control Panel and go to System (Control Panel->System and Security->System, select Advanced system settings, click on Environment Variable, In System variables section click on 'Path'). The path for Android SDK is usually C:\Users{Your laptop username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin.

   If it is not there, find the Android SDK path and it (pointing to your SDK tools bin*** location)
3. Run Windows Powershell and run the following command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"

   If it starts downloading then wait until it is finished and and run the sdkmanger command above again and finally go to VS code and click on ctrl-shift-p and write Flutter: Select Device-> Create Android Emulator and it will not show the error message.
4. If you get this error after running the sdkmanger command : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema Then you have to install multiple versions of Java because there is something wrong in the last version of Java. Download Java8 JDK from Oracle and install it. Then, copy Java8 JDK (it is usually C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271) and go to Environment variables (following the instructions in step 1). In system variables click on JAVA-HOME and paste the copied path of Java 8 instead of the path of last version and click on Ok.
5. Click on Path (in system variables) and search on the path of last java version, click on it and paste Java 8 ***bin*** location (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271*bin*) and click ok.
6. Exit the cmd and launch it (if you were using it before) and run the command: java -version You should get the following output:

   > java version "1.8.0_271"

   > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)

   > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

   Thus, we have installed Java8 JDK.
7. Now run Windows Powershell and run the following command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86" and it should start downloading.
8. Go to VS code and click on ctrl-shift-p and write Flutter: Select Device-> Create Android Emulator and it will not show the error message.
9. You can delete Java8 JDK and JRE now and reset the path of JAVA-HOME (copy the location of the last Java JDK and paste it there) and the path of ***Java bin*** to the original Path (System Variables->Path and change it to the Java bin location of the last version)

Answer (score 2):

This article is helpful for manjaro users on commandline:
[A simple, fast and lightweight Flutter dev environment on Manjaro](https://lecarvalho.medium.com/a-simple-fast-and-lightweight-flutter-dev-environment-on-manjaro-df22ae06f527)

**Steps**

- Download commandline tools only from [Android Developer's Site](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads)
- Extract the files on some /android folder
- Create a folder “latest” inside the folder /android/cmdline-tools
- Copy all the files into the “latest” folder
- Add the bin folder to the PATH environment variable:

  export PATH=/path/to/android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem too, here is what i did differently.

1. Install android studio.
2. Open Android studio > More Actions > Virtual Device Manager > Create device > Select Device > Select System Image "Orea version 27"
3. Make sure your hard disk have enough free space to run the emmulator.
4. On VS code, navigate to lib > main.dart.
5. Right click on main.dart > click on "Start Debugging"
   [image]

Comment: This helped a lot. FWIW "Start debugging" seems to build a Windows application by default. Using `Ctrl+Shift+P` and using the command `Flutter: Launch Emulator` allowed me to pick the phone that I set up with your method.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell

Android SDK\tools\bin>   .\sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the Android emulator you're trying to use doesn't have the required system image installed. I encountered this error while attempting to run an Android emulator in VSCode on my new MacBook before properly configuring it.

To resolve this issue, you first need to make sure that the SDK tools required to use the Android emulator are installed. To do this:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. In the top nav bar, click Tools -> SDK Manager.
3. Click SDK Tools, (highlighted in blue).
4. Check `Android Emulator` and `Android SDK Platform-Tools`.
5. Click `Apply` followed by `Ok`, then `Finish` once the installation is complete.

Once you've installed the SDK tools, create a device by following these steps:

1. In Android Studio, in the top nav bar, click Tools -> Device Manager.
2. Click `Create Device` then select the device.
3. In the 'System Image' screen, select a system image. If you're not sure which one to select, click the API level distribution chart link on the right panel next to the list of system images.
4. Click 'Next' and wait for the operating system image to download.
5. Once the download is complete, the emulator device will appear in the Device Manager in Android Studio. Note that if you're using VSCode, you'll need to restart it for the new emulator to appear.

Comment: @tchrist No, my answer was not generated by an AI. If you actually followed the steps, you'll see that I used a recent version of Android Studio, which an AI language wouldn't have up-to-date data on. You can see also how detailed my answer is and if you look at my previous answers, you'll see that I use the same format. I only answer questions for errors that I have been stuck on.

Comment: Alright, thanks for getting back to me. I withdraw my concern.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have an Image to create an Emulator.

Install Android Studio and follow these instructions.

[image: Step One - Open Virtual Device Manager]

[image: Step Two - Click on Create Virtual Device]

We will not complete the virtual device creation process so choose any device definition as we just need to get to the next step and install the image.

Press Next.

[image: Step Three - Coose a device definition]

Finally dowload any image of your choice and after download completes. Cancel the process of creating a virtual device and continue Emulator creation from the VScode or free feel to continue.

[image: Step 4 - Download the image that is causing this issue.]