# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema EXCEPTION

Tags: android, flutter

Hi Guys i have problem with install  **sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"**

when i enter this code, then it sends me an exception:

[image]

i read i must install java sdk 8   so i installed
after i must  indicate path so i do it and again i have this EXception

i will add i checked flutter doctor and this my result:
[image]

link to articles that I supported: [No Suitable Android AVD Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679339/no-suitable-android-avd-available/65630598)

Version java:

[image]

paths that had to be entered in the supported article:

[image]

Path:[image]

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screen shot. Instead copy the text to clipboard and paste it into your question as pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 19):

Carefully check the Android SDK directory, there are two versions of `sdkmanager.bat` if you have installed a recent version of Android SDK.  For older versions make sure the package **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)** is installed.

The first in `tools\bin` the other in `cmdline-tools\latest\bin` - the one will work, other not.

#### The recent version you should use

The version located in `cmdline-tools\latest\bin` is the one you should use. It is compatible with Java 9+ and will not cause the problems you have encountered.

#### The outdated version you should not use

The version in `tools\bin` is outdated and is incompatible with Java 9+. If you execute it with a Java Runtime greater than 8 you will get the following err or:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Until Google finally removes this version of sdkmanager I would recommend to make sure the `tools\bin` folder is not in your `PATH` environment.
Alternatively you can simply rename `tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat` so that it is no longer executed when you execute `sdkmanager`.

The whole story about why this is not yet fixed can be found in [Google issue 67495440](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67495440).

Comment: I've been having this problem for a long time, in many different ways. Thank you very much for clarifying this.

Comment: In my Android SDK I see no `cmdline-tools` directory...

Comment: I see I have to install **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)** in my **SDK Manager** to get that.

Comment: I made a fresh installation of Android Studio on a fresh machine and facing such problems while trying to compile a templated project is very discouraging. I never faced such issues in any Microsoft tool.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. In my case, tools/bin/sdkmanager works on java 1.8 and cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager works on java 11.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I've been looking at it for the past hour without being able to figure out what's wrong with my Java install etc.