# How to install AVD on VS code?

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

The error is saying that:
"No suitable Android AVD system images are available.You may need to install these using sdkmanager, for example:
sdkmanager "system-images; android-27; google_apis_playstore;x86"

Can someone help me out with it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can get any emulators running in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090813/i-can-get-any-emulators-running-in-vs-code)

Comment: There's no way around , you have to download an suitable SDK , my preffered way is downloading android studio as it will download all other sdk and stuff, but this can be done manually as well. Reason: To compile your application to an AVD it requires an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to SetUp Emulator For VSCode?**

From version [2.13.0 of Dart Code](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-13/#v2130), emulators can be launched directly from within code but This feature relies on support from the Flutter tools which means it will only show emulators when using a very recent Flutter SDK. Flutter’s master channel already has this change, but it may take a little longer to filter through to the dev and beta channels.

We have tested this feature and worked very well on flutter version **0.5.6-pre.61**

You do not need Android Studio to create or run a Virtual Device. Just use sdkmanager and avdmanager from the android sdk tools.

- Use the sdkmanager to download a system image of Android for the x86 system. e.g. sdkmanager “system-images;android-21;default;x86_64
- Then create a new virtual device using avd manager. e.g. avdmanager create avd –name AndroidDevice01 –package “system-images;android-21;default;x86_64”
- Then run the new virtual device using the emulator. If you don’t have it just install it using the sdkmanager. e.g. emulator -avd AndroidDevice01
- If you restart VSCode and load your Flutter project. The new device should show up at the bottom right of the footer.

For those people using a Mac, you can go to your terminal and type

```
$ open -a Simulator.app
```

and this command will open the simulator. After that, just go to the Debug option and tap on “Start Debugging”

**If you want to test with an Android Emulator:**

What I did was to go first to Android Studio and open a virtual Device with AVD Manager. After that, you’ll see other devices in your Visual Studio Code.

In the bottom right you’ll see now that you have 2 devices connected. Now, you can test with any of these devices.

So You can use the ‘[Android iOS Emulator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate)‘ plugin and Add the **Android Studio** Emulator script to your settings in **Visual Studio Code**:

Mac:

```
emulator.emulatorPath": "~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

Windows:

```
emulator.emulatorPath": "<your android home>\\Sdk\\emulator\\emulator.exe
```

Linux:

```
emulator.emulatorPath": "~/Documents/SDK/tools
```

Your visual studio code settings are found here: **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Setting** -> **User Setting** -> **Extensions** -> Emulator Configuration. Open command palette Cmd-Shift-P -> Type Emulator.

```
ctrl+shift+p
```

then type:

```
Flutter:launch emulator
```

run this command in your **VS code terminal** flutter emulators then see the result if you have installed any emulator it will show you, then to run one of them use **flutter emulators** **–launch your_emulator_id** in my case **flutter emulators** **–launch** Nexus 6 API 28 but if you haven’t installed any emulator you can install one with **flutter emulators –create [–name xyz]** then run your project flutter run inside the root directory of the project.

You can review the full answer from the following [link](https://flutteragency.com/setup-emulator-for-vscode/)

Comment: You shouldn't just copy almost all the text from another webpage and then link it at the end, a link as a comment was enough.